# Changing the currency format for product prices within Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm upgrading spree to from spree 1.0 to 1.3 and get stuck with the new currency options.

I want to render prices as: '€ 100' but instead get '€100'. How do I get a space between the unit and the value?

Note: Changing the locale file doesn't work, since it uses the money gem.

Answer (score 6):

There are a bunch of ways to do this.  The easiest would probably be to re-register the Euro currency with a different symbol.

Put the following in an initializer:

```
# encoding: utf-8
Money::Currency.register({
    :priority        => 1,
    :iso_code        => "EUR",
    :iso_numeric     => "978",
    :name            => "Euro",
    :symbol          => "€ ",
    :subunit         => "Cent",
    :subunit_to_unit => 100,
    :separator       => ".",
    :delimiter       => "," 
})
```

A rails console now reports:

```
> Spree::Money.new(100, currency: 'EUR')
=> € 100.00
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following in my `config/initializers/spree.rb` to inject a different symbol:

```
Money::Currency.table[:chf].merge!(symbol: 'CHF ')
```

This way the currencies aren't going to mix up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot.
In my case, used the following to change the symbol generated by the to_html method, in case anyone has the same problem.

```
# encoding: utf-8
Money::Currency.register({
    :priority        => 1,
    :iso_code        => "CLP",
    :iso_numeric     => "152",
    :name            => "Chilean Peso",
    :symbol          => "$",
    :subunit         => "Peso",
    :subunit_to_unit => 1,
    :separator       => ",",
    :delimiter       => ".",
    html_entity: "$"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the following in an initializer, e.g. `config/initializers/currency_formatting.rb`:

```
# Display prices with a space between symbol and number:
Spree::Money.default_formatting_rules[:symbol_before_without_space] = false
```

This hooks into the formatting rules found in [`Spree::Money`](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/money.rb), which can control all the [formatting Options of the Money Gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/money/Money/Formatting), including the one placing a space between the symbol and the number. This has the advantage over the other solutions presented here that it works with all currencies at once.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was pretty easy. As of gem version `money(6.16.0)`.
In Spree intializer `spree.rb` Recommended way:

```
Spree.config do |config|
  ...  
  ...

  # Below is deprecated 
  Spree::Money.default_formatting_rules[:symbol_before_without_space] = false

  # Instead try this 
  Spree::Money.default_formatting_rules[:format] = '%u %n'

end
```